# How to solve the differential equation $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=ay^{-2}$

Tags: calculus

How to solve the following differential equation to get $y$ as a function of $x$:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{a}{y^2}$$

Comment: Integrating twice OK for $ a/x^2$ at right.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Abbreviating $y(x)=y,$

$$y'' = \frac{a}{y^2}\tag1$$

Multiply both sides by $ 2 y^{'}$ and integrate

$$y'^2  = \frac{-2a}{y} +c $$

$$ x= \int \frac {\sqrt y dy}{\sqrt{  c y -2 a }} \tag2 $$

Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

Usually in a DE course, as part of the chapter on 1st-order equations, two special cases of 2nd-order equations are mentioned:  1.  No dependent variable and 2. No independent variable.  This equations is the second kind.  The trick is to let $w=y'$ and then express $y''$ in terms of $\frac{dw}{dy}$ so that $y$ plays the role of the independent variable.

$$y'' = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = \frac{dw}{dx} = \frac{dw}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dw}{dy}w.$$

Your equation becomes

$$w\frac{dw}{dy} = \frac{a}{y^2}$$

which is 1st-order separable.  Once you know $w=y' =$ crud, integrate to get $y$.